# is there an easy way to find code that is preventing event default?

Tags: javascript

This issue has come up for me a few times:

I write some code that handles an event, for example a click. I click the element and nothing happens. Some other code is calling `e.preventDefault()` before my code has the chance to handle it.

**Question:**
Is there a way to find the code that is preventing default that i have overlooked?

I usually solve this by running javascript profiler in firebug and looking at every function that is called during the click (not inside jquery etc) that may be doing the evil. There has to be a better way.

Comment: [visual events](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) might be helpful.

Comment: tried it. it didnt tell me anything new - an interesting tool that ill use again.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a test alert in the function that is supposed to execute, starting at the top and then moving it downwards after each statement. If the alert doesn't execute at the top of the function I would check your HTML element and how you are selecting it. If everything appears to be good, I would search your files using possible element selectors.

Comment: right, my event code does not execute at all. Searching for selectors will work up to a point. If an element is deep in the html i can give you 100 different selectors that will match it, moreover an event triggered on the elements children will bubble up to it.

Comment: Yeah it gets rough further down the DOM tree... Honestly, if you're still having problems, I would rebuild the page starting from the element that is having the problem. This may seem like a long way about solving your issue, but eliminating other factors will get you to the source of the problem faster... and rebuilding a page that you're familiar with will take less time then you think. Hope this helps.